# How to tell if user is submitting a form with changed values, in a Spring MVC-based webapp?

Tags: java, forms, spring-mvc

In a Spring MVC webapp, I have a form and a corresponding controller. In the controller, I need to know if the user changed any values in the form, so that I know whether to update a "changed_on" column in a status table in my database.

I don't care to know *which* field changed, and I'll save the user's data regardless. But if the user changed A->B and then back to A before they submitted, I don't want to consider that a change. I only want to update the date/time column if the user is actually changing data, because I need to know at a later point when the user last changed their data.

What's the best way to achieve this? Is it better to do it on the back-end, or the front-end? This seems like a **very** general problem: how to tell if the user is changing data on a form.

I've come up with a few potential solutions. My form fields are booleans, integers, strings and enums.

### Front-end solutions

1. Set a hidden form field using an `onChange` or `onBlur` listener in Javascript.
2. Use a jQuery [callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025396/jquery-form-change) with `$("form :input").change()`, and use `.data()` to set a `changed` value to `true`.

### Back-end solutions

1. In the form class that the web form is bound to (via `@InitBinder("formName")` in my controller), override `hashCode()` based on all of the fields I'm interested in monitoring for a change. Because I'm not using my form classes in any collections, or passing to Hibernate, I don't envision any bad side effects of this. Here's an implementation using Guava:

   ```
   @Override
   public int hashCode() {
       return Objects.hashCode(this.field1, this.field2, etc.);
   }
   ```

   Then I can compare the old form object (created in the `get()` method) with the new one created by the `WebDataBinder` from the submitted form values. If the hashes are different, then the user changed something.

   The question I have with this approach is, how do I keep the old form object around? Is there a way to stuff it in the page's `ModelAndView`, that will survive from the GET to the POST? Or could I just re-create it in my `doPost()` method, by reloading the persistent entity that's based on from the db? If Hibernate caches my entities, then re-creating the original form object - before persisting any new changes - should be pretty quick.
2. Similar to #1, but using reflection instead of a hard-coded reliance on individual fields. This way, if any new form fields are added, we won't forget to add them to the `hashCode()` method. Here's an implementation:

   ```
   public static boolean hasFormChanged(Object form1, Object form2) {
       return HashCodeBuilder.reflectionHashCode(form1) != HashCodeBuilder.reflectionHashCode(form2);
   }
   ```

   Now, I know that reflection is slow; in my tests, about 8-12x slower than the `Objects.hashCode()` approach above. However, I only have ~4 form fields, and in tests on my local machine the reflection-based method is taking about 3.5 *microseconds* per call. The other downside of reflection is that we'd need to be mindful of adding any new instance variables to the form class (or its parent class(es)), that we *don't* want to include in the comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For front end solution, you can implement more generic example, which can be applied to any page. On page load, iterate over `form` elements, then iterate over every field of the form and save its names and values

For example,

`["form1", {field1: "value1"}, {field2 : "value2"}]`  etc

Right before submit, you can check whether new form values are equal to old form values, and add additional property "changed"

Every front-end solution is ugly. Of course better to make it on server-side

You can store old object in httpSession, or you can request it second time (note hibernate does not use cache by default). What is the sense of using `hashCode` instead of `equals` ? There a small possibility of collision, when not the same objects return same hashCode

The most straightforward approach - request your object second time from Db, and use equals to compare them

Comment: With overriding `equals()`, I am more worried about messing something up that depends on object equality. I.e. if Spring ever gets more than one instance of my form object, and relies on `equals()` to compare them, I'll be changing that behavior. Whereas with `hashCode()` I'm not overriding any behavior in a way that could conceivably mess anything up. I just have to comfortable with the likelihood of getting false positive/negatives, which I think is very, very small.

Comment: You should not worry about that (impossible to break anything). After all, if you still worried, just create new method, which will compare your object field by field without overriding anything

Comment: I ended up using a back-end solution for this:  `EqualsBuilder#reflectionEquals()`. It's performance was 8-10x slower than hard-coding every field with an `EqualsBuilder`, but still so ridiculously fast that it will probably add a few microseconds to the request time. It also prevents me from having to implement `equals()` across all 15 of my form classes, and keep them up-to-date whenever form fields are added, renamed, or removed. Thanks for your help.