# How to check whether user did some changes in web page in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

There is a form in web page have 50 Questions with Radio as answer and Textbox for Comments.

There is "Submit" Button and "Save" Button and "Close Window" Button.

a) When User fills the form and in between, clicks on "Save" Button. This saves all filled data to Database and same form reload again.

b) When User click "Submit" button, whole information get submitted and everything is done i.e same page does not reload again.

c) when user click "Close Window", then user is confirmed:
1) Save and Close
2) Close, Without Save

**Requirement**:

If user fills form and clicks SAVE button first, The same page gets reload. But after that, without any changes to web page, if user Clicks "Close Window" button. Then it should not ask 1) Save and Close. That means, it should only ask Save and Close, if User have done any changes.

How can we do this in JQuery/Javascript?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025396/jquery-form-change

Comment: Look at this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155739/detecting-unsaved-changes

Comment: Keep a hidden field whose value will be true after postback. An check this value in window.onbeforeunload