# jQuery on form submit works, but on form change does not

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify

I just want to get this jQuery to work. When I do this it writes to the console just fine:

```
$('body').on('submit', 'form[action="/cart"]', function(event){
  console.log("I don't think this is getting here");
});
```

But when I do this it doesn't write to the console:

```
$('body').on('change', 'form[action="/cart"]', function(event){
  console.log("I don't think this is getting here");
});
```

my test website anyone can see is at http://test-4658.myshopify.com this script is on the cart. You can add and update stuff in the cart to verify.

EDIT:
Some other ideas I've tried, with no luck:

```
$('form[action="/cart"] :input').click(function() {
  if($(this).closest('form[action="/cart"]').data('changed')) {
  console.log("I don't think this is getting here");
  }
});
```

And:

```
$('body').on('change', 'form[action="/cart"] :input', function(event){
  console.log("I don't think this is getting here");
});
```

Where did I go astray?

Comment: I strongly suspect that the form element does not have a change event. You would have to change the selector to detect change on any input/select/textarea child of the form maybe.

Comment: Form change event does work, see example: https://jsfiddle.net/q6rzgzq4/ -- must be something else

Comment: `change` event relies on the `value` of an element which `form`s don't have. Try monitoring for `change` on one of the `form`'s elements/inputs.

Comment: makes sense.. let me see. but I thought that by using the `form` selector it selected all the child elements in the form? But maybe not..

Comment: Well, I was surprised that forms had a change event too - but your jsfiddle does work... Even when I put in your form selector: https://jsfiddle.net/q6rzgzq4/2/

Comment: Note that while capturing the `change` event on the `form` works (as per Will P's fiddle) it is not the `form` that's raising the event. It's relying on the event bubbling up through the DOM from the `input`, in the same way that a delegated event handler would. OP, make sure there's no other elements which are trapping that event and call `stopPropagation()` or `return false;`

Comment: @ToddT, first - it's impossible to add items to the cart in your link without login (and probably register first). Second - it will be much easier to help if you create a working example (demo) in jsfiddle/snippet to show the problem.

Comment: @Dekel and everyone else, sorry about that, turned off the login necessary for the cart add

Comment: Doesn't work. Please check with incognito (or logout and check before update that "everything works")

Comment: This might be a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025396/how-do-you-handle-a-form-change-in-jquery#3025505

Comment: No I don't think so, I've tried that answer and its not working for me, I've updated the question with the other things I've tried.

Comment: Without fixing the login problem it's impossible to help

Comment: Why event delegation - use normal event binding and think does element has such event. I don't like using delegation without reason.

Comment: It ended up being a timing issue. The cart had not rendered before the script was run. I found another way! Thank you everyone